# An arc in $\mathbb{R}^2$ whose elements are pairwise "monotone"

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, monotone-operator-theory

Assume we have an arc
\begin{eqnarray*}
\varphi:[0,1] &\rightarrow& \mathbb{R}^2, \\
t &\mapsto& (x(t),y(t)),
\end{eqnarray*}
i.e., $\varphi$ is continuous and injective. Suppose that $x(0)<x(1)$, and we have the following "pairwise monotone" condition:
\begin{equation*}
\big( (x(t)-x(s)\big)\big( y(t)-y(s)\big) \ge 0,\quad \forall t,s\in [0,1].
\end{equation*}

**My question is that:** for any $0<t<1$, can we prove that $x(0)\le x(t)\le x(1)$? And hence $y(0)\le y(t)\le y(1)$.

I first started with assuming, contrary to the claim, that there is $t\in (0,1)$ for which $x(t)<x(0)$ (the other case where $x(t)>x(1)$ should be handled similarly). Then the arc would go down from $(x(0),y(0))$ to $(x(t),y(t))$ and then at some time being pulled up to $(x(1),y(1))$ which breaks the pairwise monotone condition around the point $(x(t),y(t)$. I believe the Intermediate Value Theorem should be taken into account, but still cannot "control" simultaneously $x$ and $y$ coordinates.

Thank you for your reading. Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume, wlog, $x(0) = y(0) = 0$. All points of the arc will be in the first or third quadrants. It can't pass through the origin again as it is 1-1, so it must stay in one quadrant.

Comment: Thank you so much! It was very clear.